# KeepAlive messages in Bittorrent protocol

Tags: java, bittorrent

I can't find the answer to this question anywhere on the Internet. I was wondering what happens when you receive a keep alive message on a bittorrent protocol? are we suppose to send a keep alive message back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Unofficial BitTorrent Specification](http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#keep-alive:_.3Clen.3D0000.3E):

> #### keep-alive: `<len=0000>`
>
> The **keep-alive** message is a message with zero bytes, specified with the length prefix set to zero. There
> is no message ID and no payload. Peers may close a connection if they
> receive no messages (**keep-alive** or any other message) for a
> certain period of time, so a keep-alive message must be sent to
> maintain the connection alive if no command have been sent for a given
> amount of time. This amount of time is generally two minutes.

I'm no BitTorrent expert, but based on this and what knowledge of network protocols I *do* have, it sounds like the answer to your question

> are we suppose to send a keep alive message back?

is **no.** As for

> what happens when you receive a keep alive message?

well, nothing — what matters is what happens when you *don't* receive a keep-alive (or any other) message after the mentioned "given amount of time." In a BitTorrent implementation, receiving a keep-alive message would probably reset a timer, or update a "last message received" timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Bittorrent Specification](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html):

> Messages of length zero are keepalives, and ignored. Keepalives are generally sent once every two minutes, but note that timeouts can be done much more quickly when data is expected.

In other words, the keep-alive is effectively a no-op.
Like all other messages, it resets the timeout, so it has the net effect of just "keeping the connection alive" for another 2 minutes.